# Stripe API call (Payment Intent creation) failed: x509 certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: docker, go, stripe-payments

I am trying to instantiate a PaymentIntent on the server-side (using Go) just like [this example](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart?payment_intent=pi_3KPiBcIPedPoXQNK1OqdvqWr&payment_intent_client_secret=pi_3KPiBcIPedPoXQNK1OqdvqWr_secret_WbhzoS2xznWhC5uyWm7f36M97&redirect_status=succeeded) but met with this error `Request failed with error: Post "https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`. I have made sure to assign the test secret key like below, but the error still persists. Does it have something to do with SSL certificate? I am testing my app locally using Docker (localhost).

My code:

```
import (
    "github.com/stripe/stripe-go"
    "github.com/stripe/stripe-go/paymentintent"
)

func CreateStripePaymentIntent(subtotal float32) (string, error) {
    // Create a PaymentIntent with amount and currency
    stripe.Key = os.Getenv("STRIPE_SECRET_KEY")

    fmt.Println(stripe.Key)

    params := &stripe.PaymentIntentParams{
        Amount:   stripe.Int64(int64(subtotal)),
        Currency: stripe.String(string(stripe.CurrencyUSD)),
    }

    pi, err := paymentintent.New(params)

    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("pi.New: %v", err) // =======> ERROR HERE WHEN CALLING STRIPE API
    }


    return pi.ClientSecret, nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I run the server using `scratch` Docker image, there is no SSL certificate to use. Just need to copy the certs from first stage (Mine is a multi-staged build) `COPY --from=builder /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/`